# How to avoid logparser from storing input file name in each row?

Tags: windows, parsing, logparser

I'm parsing a log file (IIS file) using [logparser](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24659) and works great but when I open generated file (csv) its first column is logfile name e.g.  *c:\temp\in_290414.log* which is the input file.

How can I avoid it? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just be explicit in your SELECT clause with the fields you want out of the IIS log:

```
SELECT time, date, url, etc INTO output.csv FROM ...
```

Comment: I was looking for a short cut or trick but yes that is an answer and nobody can deny it :)  Thanks though